# Is there a way to print a multiline pattern on JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()?

Tags: java, joptionpane, multiline

So I was wondering if there is a way to output a multiline pattern with stars (*) like a triangle or a pyramid on JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(). I know that this works like that: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello World!"); but instead of Hello World! I need to print on the new window that pops up a hollow pyramid and I can't figure it out. Can you help me? Thanks in advance. I've added the code that prints the hollow pyramid. The variable L is the height of the pyramid and it is provided by the user whenever the program is executed. So how can I print this pattern with a variable height in a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()?

```
for(int row=1;row<=L;row++){
    for(int col=1;col<=L+L-1;col++){
        if(row==L || row+col==L+1 || col-row==L-1) System.out.print("*");
        else System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing text a few characters at a time to `System.out`, you should append the characters to a String variable (or ideally `StringBuilder` for better performance).

```
// create an empty string and generate the pyramid by adding characters
String pyramid = "";
for (int row = 1; row <= L; row++) {
    for (int col = 1; col <= L + L - 1; col++) {
        if (row == L || row + col == L + 1 || col - row == L - 1) pyramid += "*";
        else pyramid += " ";
    }
    pyramid += "\n";
}
// outputs the same thing as all the tiny System.out writes in the original question
System.out.println(pyramid);
```

For a smaller academic problem, it is not totally necessary to optimize this; however, for future reference, you should use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) when concatenating a significant amount of tiny strings. The reason I mention this is that internally, when you "add" (i.e. concatenate) two strings together, you are actually allocating another new string each time. This can add up to a lot of new allocations for strings when used in a loop.

---

Note that the default font with `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)` is not mono-spaced by default, meaning characters have variable length width. Trying to effectively display ASCII art might not work well. This can be circumvented by using a uneditable transparent text area:

```
JTextArea textbox = new JTextArea(pyramid);
textbox.setOpaque(false);
textbox.setEditable(false);
textbox.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 12));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textbox, "Pyramid", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

This yields:
[image: L=15 pyramid]

Comment: I knew that  I can use the newline character, the problem is that the height of the pyramid is stored in a variable and the user determines the height each time the program is executed. So that's not a solution to my problem. I will add something to the main problem to help you understand better so watch out for it. Thank you for your time

Comment: @AntonisChliaras That should have been clearly articulated - there was no mention of this additional constraint in the initial post.

Comment: Yes it was my bad for not clarifying that. I'm so sorry.

Comment: @AntonisChliaras I have updated my answer. Does this make sense to you and satisfy your constraints?

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped me a lot. It makes perfect sense to me and works perfectly.